# Optimizing python dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, optimization

The objective is to get the 3 highest values under each id and assign "primary","secondary", "tertiary" in that order.
For example d_id = 1 has values of 100, 200 , 300 for x1 , x2, x3 ( which are store groups).
So for d_id = 1 , x3 will be the primary store and so on.
Below is the code for the process.

```
cols = ["d_id", "primary", "secondary","tertiary"]
scoring_results = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols, index = scoreperseg.index)

zz = len(scoreperseg)
d_count = 0
for index, row in scoreperseg.iterrows():

    d_count += 1

    row_sorted = row.sort_values(ascending=False)

    scoring_results.ix[index]['d_id']            = index
    scoring_results.ix[index]['primary']         = segment_map[row_sorted[0:3].idxmax()][1][0]
    scoring_results.ix[index]['secondary']       = segment_map[row_sorted[1:3].idxmax()][1][0]
    scoring_results.ix[index]['tertiary']        = segment_map[row_sorted[2:3].idxmax()][1][0]

Segment_Map Key         
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D' s14         
['Premiums']    s14         
['Movies']  s14         
Score_Per_Seg               
d_id    s2  s41 s47 s14
3   0   0   0   0.002507676
225 0   0   0   0
Scoring_Result              
d_id    segment segment_genre       
3   Premium Movies
```

@COLDSPEED
is this helpful?
So , for the above example, I need to sort each row in score_per_seg , get the 3 highest values of segments and then find the indexes of those segments in segment map and then store the values in those indexes from segment map in scoring results   as primary , secondary, tertiary.
I hope this is clear enough to understand.

There are more than 5 million d_id's and this process currently take more than 2 hours to complete.
Is there any way to optimize these operations.
I have tried searching for parallel operations but that won't work here I think.
Can someone please guide me on this?
Segment_Map contains how many times on an average a household has shopped from a particular store in a year.

Comment: No... this isn't what we need. We need to see your data and your expected output, and a brief description of what you're trying to do. Code is useful but not one it's own.

Comment: Sorting a large set only to get the 3 highest value is inefficient on a algorithmic point of view. Doing it *by hand* should require 3*n operations when best sorts are in O(n log 2). So just ask for highest value, remove it, and iterate 2 times.

Comment: Sounds like there are 5m rows, not rows of length 5m. Anyway - profile it. No point in guessing. (And consider whether it's got sufficient memory)

Comment: Added the example input and expected output please.